# discrete distribution returns integers out of bound

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, distribution, sampling

I wrote the function below to sample without replacement. It returns a `vector<int>` representing a sample being picked among some points. As input, I have a `vector<double>` containing the probabilities and an integer for the desired sample size. For the function, I use the discrete distribution:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/discrete_distribution/discrete_distribution/

```
vector<int> samplingwoutreplacement(vector<double> probs, int samplesize) {
    random_device rd;
    mt19937 generator(rd());
    vector<int> sample;
    sample.reserve(samplesize);
    for (int i = 0; i < samplesize; i++) {
        discrete_distribution<int> distribution(probs.begin(), probs.end());
        int currentpick = distribution(generator);
        if (currentpick >= probs.size()) {
            cout  << endl << "error: range overstepped; current pick is: " << currentpick << endl;
            cout << "probs.size = " << probs.size() << endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < probs.size(); j++) {
                cout << probs[j] << endl;
            }
        }
        probs[currentpick] = 0;
        sample.push_back(currentpick);
    }
    return sample;
}
```

In my application, I used this sampling a lot of times and after a lot of iterations, the discrete distribution returns an integer larger than the size of the vector containing the probabilities. (More precisely, my vector had size 178, and I got as a return 178, but should get something between an integer between 0 and 177.) How can this happen?

Comment: `rd` and `generator` should be `static`. `distribution` should be outside the loop. `rd` isn't even needed, really. You could go `mt19937 generator(random_device{}());`

Comment: I'm not getting that error. I tried with a sample size of 10M. Making the tweaks I suggest above, my program also runs faster.

Comment: I want to pick repeatedly numbers, but eliminate the possibility of repetition. Therefore, I set the probability for a picked number to 0 and initialize distribution with the updated probabilities. So, distribution should not be outside the loop in my opinion.

Comment: Right, gotcha. Glossed over that part. Moving the distribution back in still doesn't trigger the error.

Comment: Are individual weights actually needed? Or are they just weighted equally?

Comment: The individual weights are key. I uploaded the output where the distribution failed here: https://pastebin.com/3gyVVCEZ  (If there is one alternative to post that, which is more common on stackoverflow, please tell me.)

Comment: I was asking because if the weights don't matter, `std::sample` would work perfectly. However, I simply cannot replicate your error.

Comment: @MPB94 you data is the problem - I don't know what do you expect if you have probabilities like 2.29634e+293. You feed code garbage data, but expecting good output

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux My question is, why is it garbage? The probs (it is a little bit misleading) are the weights and then the distribution is supposed to produce probabilites proportional to the weights. I suppose the problem is that the sum of weights is too large and then all probabilities end up to be 0.

Comment: On the face of it, this looks like a bug in the implementation. Which compiler/standard library version are you using?

Comment: To be more explicit: the weights in the pastebin link will sum to INFINITY (6.46e307 + 1.29e308 > 1.9e308 > DBL_MAX), and this could easily exercise an under-tested corner case in the library implementation.

Comment: @halfflat Well, you could sort weights (and while sorting check for NaN, Inf, ...), and then divide by largest weight and then do summation. So there could be workarounds, and I advice to fill out bug report against particular implementation of the C++ std library

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Indeed, I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C++ Standard, we can read about `std::discrete_distribution` at [26.6.8.6.1 [rand.dist.samp.discrete]](https://eel.is/c++draft/rand#dist.samp.discrete-2) (emphasis mine)

> A `discrete_­distribution` random number distribution produces random integers *i, 0 ≤ i < n*, distributed according to the discrete probability function
> *P*(*i* | *p<sub>0</sub>, …, p<sub>n−1</sub>*) = *p<sub>i</sub>*.
>
> Unless specified otherwise, the distribution parameters are calculated as: *p<sub>k</sub>* = *w<sub>k</sub>*/*S* for *k = 0, …, n−1,* in which **the values *w<sub>k</sub>***, commonly known as the **weights**, **shall be non-negative, non-NaN, and non-infinity**.
> **Moreover, the following relation shall hold: 0 < S = w<sub>0</sub> + ⋯ + w<sub>n−1</sub>**.

Some of the weights used by the asker (like 1.29272e+308) are so big that their sum overflows the range of `double`, so that the value of *S* (which become infinity) and the following calculations become meaningless.

I tested the behavior of gcc, clang and MSVC in such corner case and find out that while gcc and clang produce a distribution with all probabilities equal to zero and `std::discrete_distribution::operator()` always returns *n - 1*, MSVC also produces a distribution with all probabilities equal to zero, *but* the integer returned is always *n* (an out of bounds value, as experienced by the asker).

To my interpretation, that's not a standard compliant behavior, even if, to their credit, OP's input parameters result in a violation of the preconditions.

Comment: As quoted here, it doesn't exclude the sum from being infinite, only the weights.

Comment: @halfflat But if the sum goes to infinity, *all* the probabilities become 0 (see e.g. this [sample](https://godbolt.org/z/frWf7h)).

Comment: Sure, it's almost certainly not useful, but it still shouldn't give a value out of the permissible range. Even with sane weights, there's no guarantee that sum (w_i/S) will actually equal 1 exactly, so the implementation already has to deal with this sort of problem to some degree.

Comment: @halfflat I get your point and even if it could be considered a violation of the preconditions, IMHO, `operator()` shouldn't be allowed to return a value outside the range. The only compiler with which I could reproduce the faulty behavior was [MSVC](https://rextester.com/RETGKJ10728).

Comment: @Bob__ thanks for your  thorough and helpful answer. It is quite interesting that this behaviour does not occur with gcc and clang. I use MS Visual Studio 19.

Comment: @MPB94 You are welcome. Note that gcc and clang's behavior in this case isn't much better, they still not warn you that the distribution isn't correctly initialized and the resulting program isn't correct either. Returning one past the maximum value is at least a *signal* (if checked) that something is wrong. In both cases, checking that the sum of the probabilities is nowhere near to one is a good hint that something went wrong (IMHO that should be done by the implementation, but the standard doesn't mandate it). You may check (and transform) the weights *before* constructing the distrib.

Comment: @Bob__ Yes, this behaviour at least signals that something is not working as wished. I also thought about adjusting the weights by normalizing them, but then on the other side, very low weights will become zero, I guess. That's better at least, but not perfect.